# Does Magento have an image gallery like wordpress?

Tags: image, product-images, image-upload

I want to bulk upload images to be used later.  Is that default in Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, but it is for CMS content and not available to use for products and categories.

For products, you can certainly upload in bulk to the `media/import` directory, and then use these images at a later date by running an import, referencing those files in the import file.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of extensions for galleries on Magento stores (for example [this](https://www.magenmagic.com/media-gallery-pro-for-magento))